# FBX model for 2d sprite charachter

Tags: unity, animation, fbx, 3d-modeling

I was following along the unity platformer tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WhZ1svdC3Q It is great. After looking the animation I found that there was a fbx model for 2d sprite character. I just want to ask can you use 3d animation like motion capture animation once you rig a character using bone for 2d(fbx model). I search but unable to find any good tutorial of how to create fbx model for 2d character and creating maps for these 2d character.

I am really confused. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Motion capture is inherently capturing the way that a three-dimensional human being moves in three-dimensional space. While it wouldn't be impossible to restrict / translate that captured motion into a 2D plane, you can expect there to be some custom transformation & adaptation or touch-up steps in between the capture and applying it to your sprites. There's no reason you can't use 3D animation tools to animate 2D characters, and in fact [many games have done this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqo4Ka9E3aU). Can you clarify what specific problem with this you need help solving?

Comment: Thank you so much DMGregory, Actually I want to do the same thing. which is shown in the video share by you. But unable to find any good tutorial to understand this type of workflow. Can you suggest any tutorial or course?

Comment: This site isn't for finding existing tutorials — a search engine will always have more a comprehensive and up-to-date index of available documents than we do. But if you can narrow your question down to the first step in the process you're stuck on, we can try to help you solve that problem. What have you tried so far, based on your knowledge of the tools and the research you've done?